# Is it worth implementing IDataErrorInfo?

Tags: c#, wpf, validation

Well, by the moment I am validating data on my way. I have this code:

In my view:

```
<TextBox Height="23" Text="{Binding Age, UpdateSourceTrigger=PropertyChanged}" HorizontalAlignment="Left" Margin="257,150,0,0" Name="txtAge" VerticalAlignment="Top" Width="54"
         Visibility="{Binding AgeVisibility}"
         IsEnabled="{Binding AgeIsEnabled}"
         ToolTip="{Binding AgeToolTip}"
         ToolTipService.ShowOnDisabled="true">
    <TextBox.Style>
        <Style TargetType="TextBox">
            <Style.Triggers>
                <DataTrigger Binding="{Binding ElementName=ucPrincipal, Path=DataContext.AgeCorrect}" Value="false">
                    <Setter Property="Background" Value="{StaticResource ResourceKey=TextBoxIncorrectValue}"/>
                </DataTrigger>
            </Style.Triggers>
        </Style>
    </TextBox.Style>
</TextBox>
```

In my view model:

```
private bool _ageCorrect = true;
public bool AgeCorrect
{
    get { return _ageCorrect; }
    set
    {
        _ageCorrect = value;
        base.RaisePropertyChangedEvent("AgeCorrect");
    }
}


private string _ageToolTip = "";
public string AgeToolTip
{
    get { return _ageToolTip; }
    set
    {
        _ageToolTip = value;
        base.RaisePropertyChangedEvent("AgeToolTip");
    }
}


private void validateAge()
{
    decimal decParsedAge;
    if(decimal.TryParse(Age, out decParsedAge) == true)
    {
        if (decParsedAge <= 0)
        {
            AgeToolTip = "Age must be greater than 0";
            AgeCorrect = false;
        }
        else
        {
            AgeCorrect = true;
        }
    }
    else
    {
        AgeToolTip = "Age must be a decimal number.";
        AgeCorrect = false;
    }
}
```

That works fine. However I am seeing some examples about the IDataErrorInfo, but really if I want a bit complex data validation, from my point of view, the code is not very different. So I am wondering if it worths to change my code to implement the IDataErrorInfo interface.

Thank so much.

Comment: this may interest you (the working example is at the very end): http://www.cnblogs.com/guogangj/archive/2013/01/03/2843495.html The example uses DataAnnotation to set limits for data and error messages.

Comment: You can user Regex for validation http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.text.regularexpressions.regex%28v=vs.110%29.aspx

Comment: Many good questions generate some degree of opinion based on expert experience, but answers to this question will tend to be almost entirely based on opinions, rather than facts, references, or specific expertise. As such, it is off topic for this website and I have voted to close it. It also seems strange to me that you would ask this question here rather than just trying to implement the 'similar code' as you called it, for yourself.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you need to display more verbose validation (other than the exceptions thrown from the view model), then implementing IDataErrorInfo in my view is a good starting point and easy to extend your view model with; just requiring two members: a string property named Error and a string
indexer.

The Error property provides an overall error string that describes the entire object (which could
be something as simple as “Invalid Data”). The string indexer accepts a property name and returns the
corresponding detailed error information. For example, if you pass an “Age” property to the string indexer, you
might receive a response such as “The age cannot be negative.”

Quoting [Matthew MacDonald](http://www.apress.com/9781430272052), "the key idea here is that properties
are set normally, without any fuss, and the indexer allows the user interface to check for invalid data".